# bitmap image setsource: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumenException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, portable-class-library, bitmapimage

in a Windows Universal app, I am trying to load an image from a portable library into a bitmap image that I will then put into an Image control. The problem I'm having is that I seem to get stuck on bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream). I've found [another user with the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6eaada1c-c2da-494f-bcce-d0ba2807adcb/hang-in-bitmapimagesetsourceasync-or-crandomaccessstreamoverstream?forum=winappswithcsharp), but a solution hasn't been found.
Do I need to do some sort of conversion on the png file?

**EDIT** I can't really call this a solution, but it works fine if I move the images out of the library and into the actual projects. I'm just going to live with it for now.

Here is my code:

```
    private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImageFromLibrary(string original)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(LibraryAsmName)); //@"MyProjectLibrary
        string imageName = original + Extension; // e.g. Hir.png
        var bm = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = ResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceStream(asm, imageName)
            .AsRandomAccessStream()) // shows a size equal to the size of the .png file
        {
            //await Task.Run(() => stream.Size); // possible online solution... Nope, didn't work.
            await bm.SetSourceAsync(stream); // gets stuck here. Output window shows "A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumenException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll"
        }
        return bm;
    }

/// <summary>
/// Utility class that can be used to find and load embedded resources into memory.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// </remarks>
public static class ResourceLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to find and return the given resource from within the specified assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The embedded resource stream.</returns>
    /// <param name="assembly">Assembly.</param>
    /// <param name="resourceFileName">Resource file name.</param>
    public static Stream GetEmbeddedResourceStream(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
    {
        var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        var resourcePaths = resourceNames
            .Where(x => x.EndsWith(resourceFileName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .ToArray();

        if (!resourcePaths.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Resource ending with {0} not found.", resourceFileName));
        }

        if (resourcePaths.Count() > 1)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Multiple resources ending with {0} found: {1}{2}", resourceFileName, Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, resourcePaths)));
        }

        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePaths.Single());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to find and return the given resource from within the specified assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The embedded resource as a byte array.</returns>
    /// <param name="assembly">Assembly.</param>
    /// <param name="resourceFileName">Resource file name.</param>
    public static byte[] GetEmbeddedResourceBytes(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
    {
        var stream = GetEmbeddedResourceStream(assembly, resourceFileName);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to find and return the given resource from within the specified assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The embedded resource as a string.</returns>
    /// <param name="assembly">Assembly.</param>
    /// <param name="resourceFileName">Resource file name.</param>
    public static string GetEmbeddedResourceString(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
    {
        var stream = GetEmbeddedResourceStream(assembly, resourceFileName);

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't place `ResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceStream()` and google only points back to here... So how about `stream == null`

Comment: I guess it helps if I include what I'm using, huh?

Comment: Yes, especially as `ResourceLoader` is an existing Fx class.

Comment: So what happens if you load it into a MemStream first and call `bm.SetSource()` ?

Comment: It says that MemoryStream is not assignable as an IRandomAccessStream

Comment: Please indicacte (tag) the exact Project type. The comment refers to Xamarin .

Comment: My apologies, I borrowed this code since it was reading an image from the Portable Class Library